# Polymorphism (C# .NET)

Tags: class, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

Apologies if this has been asked before however I have not been able to find an answer that really explains how to achieve or get around my problem.

---

The issue I am facing is how to split up code into separate classes without asking anything about the first object. For example the most common explanation of polymorphism uses:

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract String talk();
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    String talk() {
        return "Meow!";
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    String talk() {
        return "Woof!";
    }
}

void letsHear(final Animal a) {
    println(a.talk());
}

int main() {
    letsHear(new Cat());
    letsHear(new Dog());
}
```

However, what if I dint know that I wanted to create a new Dog and a new Cat. If this was a form that a user fills in and they could choose a cat or dog. Currently I would write the following solution to the problem:

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract String talk();
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    String talk() {
        return "Meow!";
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    String talk() {
        return "Woof!";
    }
}

void letsHear(final Animal a) {
    println(a.talk());
}

int main() {
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    switch(userInput){
      case "Cat": 
         letsHear(new Cat());
         break;
      case "Dog":
        letsHear(new Dog());
        break;
    }
}
```

There must be a better solution than using a case statement to find out which ID the user selected to create the class. Please let me know if the question does not make sense or this is probably the best way of solving this issue. I know my code does not compile or work but this is more of an architecture question rather than specific code that works.

Comment: Since you don't know which animal will be created at run-time, then you should use an animal factory, e.g use the "simple factory" or the "factory method" pattern. It let's you pass the animal type ('Cat', or 'Dog', or etc) and creates the corresponding animal object for you. You can then call the `letsHear()` function, passing that new created instance to it. See: [THIS](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) and [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcFVTgRHJLM&index=4&list=PLrhzvIcii6GNjpARdnO4ueTUAVR9eMBpc). Good luck!

Comment: There is a need to switch over the input unless your language allows executing Strings as code (Javascript allows this, for example).  This switching over input to instantiate an object should ideally happen at the perimeter of your application (where the data comes in, and in your case, this is the console).  You're doing this switch in main(), and @aendeerei is suggested extracting the logic to a factory, but it doesn't really make a difference, because the switch needs to happen somewhere.  The benefit of polymorphism is only really apparent when the Animal type is used in multiple places.

Comment: I agree with @jrahhali. Good thought, jrahhali! ;-) Indeed, if you directly decide on "client" part which animal should be created, then you can couple the input with the class name to be created in main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would like to thank everyone who answered my question.

So after looking at all the comments and videos on youtube, I see that this is probably the best way of solving the issue if you do not know the type you need at runtime. Therefore implementing a factory class and following the factory design pattern seems to be the cleanest way of solving this issue.

Hope this helps others in a similar position to mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that you develop in c# code then here is the right way to do it

```
class Program
{
    abstract class Animal
    {
        public abstract string talk();
    }

    class Cat : Animal
    {
        public override string talk()
        {
            return "Meow!";
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return talk();
        }
    }

    class Dog : Animal
    {
        public override string talk()
        {
            return "Woof!";
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return talk();
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Animal cat = new Cat();
        Animal dog = new Dog();

        Console.WriteLine(cat.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(dog.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```